# Can't `add JuMP` in Julia

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I'm attempting to add `JuMP`, but it's returning an error.

```
(v1.0) pkg> add JuMP
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package JuMP [4076af6c]:
 JuMP [4076af6c] log:
 ├─possible versions are: [0.1.1-0.1.2, 0.2.0, 0.3.0-0.3.2, 0.4.0-0.4.1, 0.5.0-0.5.8, 0.6.0-0.6.3, 0.7.0-0.7.4, 0.8.0, 0.9.0-0.9.3, 0.10.0-0.10.3, 0.11.0-0.11.3, 0.12.0-0.12.2, 0.13.0-0.13.2, 0.14.0-0.14.2, 0.15.0-0.15.1, 0.16.0-0.16.2, 0.17.0-0.17.1, 0.18.0-0.18.2] or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions [0.1.1-0.1.2, 0.2.0, 0.3.0-0.3.2, 0.4.0-0.4.1, 0.5.0-0.5.8, 0.6.0-0.6.3, 0.7.0-0.7.4, 0.8.0, 0.9.0-0.9.3, 0.10.0-0.10.3, 0.11.0-0.11.3, 0.12.0-0.12.2, 0.13.0-0.13.2, 0.14.0-0.14.2, 0.15.0-0.15.1, 0.16.0-0.16.2, 0.17.0-0.17.1, 0.18.0-0.18.2]
 └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: uninstalled — no versions left
```

It looks like Julia is restricting to versions: `uninstalled — no versions left`. Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JuMP isn't ready for Julia v1.0 (or v0.7) yet.

Citing from there [github page](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl):

> The latest release of JuMP (based on MathProgBase) is not compatible
>   with Julia 0.7 or 1.0. We encourage users to continue to use Julia 0.6
>   for a stable environment. The development version of JuMP (based on
>   MOI) supports both Julia 0.6 and Julia 0.7 but is alpha-quality with
>   breaking changes in still progress. See the Discourse post for more
>   information on Julia 0.7/1.0 support.

Comment: oh, guess I'll just have to wait then. Thanks!